# Ggplot geom_segment time x-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis

I have two questions about my `Gantt-chart` I'm plotting via `Ggplot2`'s `geom_segment` function:

First of all, the time-axis is scaled based on the data points, which means sometimes one step counts for `1:15` hours and the other for like 15 minutes. How do I get a constant `00:00` - `24:00` scaled timeline?

Second, when a task starts at `23:50` and its has a duration of 30 minutes, which makes the ending time `00:20`, it is plotted from `00:20` - `23:50` (almost a whole day) instead of `23:50` till the end of the x-axis (which should be `24:00`). Because the data then reaches the next day and I'm plotting for only one day, the time after `24:00` is not required to be plotted.

This is the code I'm using now:

```
ggplot(GanttArrNBStairs1208) + 
    geom_segment(aes(x=Arr_GSE_Start, xend = Arr_GSE_End, 
                     y=`Arrival Trip Number`, yend=`Arrival Trip Number`, 
                     colour=LDA_Pier_Final), 
                 size = 1) + 
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

Here is a picture of my chart:
[image: Gantt Chart via geom_segment]

Comment: To fix the x-axis, you'll need to format your times as datetimes (see `?as.POSIXct`) or a time class (see `?hms::hms`). To get a fuller answer, edit with some data [to make your example reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thanks, this answered both questions, since it now recognises the next day as well.